# Function prototype that accepts a structure belonging to another class

Tags: .net, vb.net, structure

I have a class that contains a structure which has to be passed to another function belonging to a different class. (VB.NET)

```
Public Class A_one
         Private Structure Profile
            Dim strUIConfig as String
            Dim blah blah as String
            Dim Xyz as string
         End Structure

         Dim testProfile as New Profile()
         'inititialize testProfile Here

        toObj.send_profile(testProfile)

Public Class B_one
        send_profile(ByVal x as A_one.Profile)    ' How should I provide the declaration here ?
        'blah blah blah do stuff
        p = x.strUIconfig    '???
```

I find it strange that the class A_one does not have a dll so that I can add that dll as a reference in class B - which would technically solve the problem when I import the dll of class A_one onto class B.
Is my understanding right ?

Comment: The code you've posted is kind of a mess. Is it supposed to be puesdocode or vb.net?

Comment: VB.NET
I'll try to provide the indentation. Sorry

Comment: Last i checked, VB didn't do `//` comments.  :P

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `Profile` as *private* to `A_one` - so it's not even visible within `B_one`. If you made it public, you'd be able to use:

```
send_profile(ByVal as A_one.Profile)
```

I would *generally* encourage you to avoid creating non-private nested types though. It can certainly be useful, but it can also be a bit of a pain.

Comment: But A_one is a class and not an object. Aren't you using A_one as an object in your example ?

Comment: @SharatChandra: No, I'm using it to qualify the type name. Put it this way: have you tried it?

Comment: Yes . It says A_one.Profile is not defined..ANd I did make the structure public

Comment: @SharatChandra: Odd. Based on MSDN, I have edited the answer. It doesn't look right to me, but it's worth a try. And as I said before, I probably wouldn't make it a nested type... or a structure, in fact.

Comment: What's an alternate solution to send a bunch of values from a member function of one class to a member function of another class ?

Comment: @SharatChandra: Make it a new top-level type. Why did you *want* to make it a nested type? (And default to using a class unless you *really* want value type behaviour.)

Comment: The `..::.` syntax seems to be mistake in the documentation (the same mistake is in the C# version). VB.NET seems to use `.` for accessing nested types, just like C#.

Comment: @svick: Okay, so "." should have been okay. Will edit back then. That's what I'd have expected, but I can't check right now.