# Accessing a structure of an object of another class

Tags: vb.net, structure

I have a class ClassA inside which I create an object (classB_obj) of another class ClassB. 
How can I access/set values of a structure inside ClassB, using this classB_obj ?
I'm not familiar with the syntax in vb.net. What I'm trying to do is this

```
Public ClassA
         Public Sub SomeSub 
              Dim ClassB_obj As New ClassB()   

              Dim classB_struct As ClassB.sampleStruct 'The error is **Type ClassB.sampleStruct not defined**
          End Sub
End ClassA

Public ClassB

   Private Structure Struct
       Dim xy As String
       Dim yz As String
   End Structure

   Dim sampleStruct As Struct

   'Member functions here
 End ClassB
```

The error is **Type ClassB.sampleStruct not defined**

Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong. Newbie to vb.net here and unfamiliar with syntax.
Thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function prototype that accepts a structure belonging to another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397238/function-prototype-that-accepts-a-structure-belonging-to-another-class)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the members of `Class B` that are allowed to be accessed outside the class to `Public`

```
Public ClassB

   Public Structure Struct
       Dim xy As String
       Dim yz As String
   End Structure

   'Public sampleStruct As Struct

End ClassB

Public ClassA
   Public Sub SomeSub 
        'Dim ClassB_obj As New ClassB()   
        Dim classb_struct As ClassB.Struct
   End Sub
End ClassA
```

Comment: I did that but didn't work as well.
And how should I use the structure classB_struct in classA ?
    `Dim classB_struct As ClassB.sampleStruct` is ok ?

Comment: Yes That's what I did in my code.but typed it wrong here. Still not working :/.

Comment: @SharatChandra i'm sorry, try this instead `Dim classb_struct As ClassB.Struct`. `Structure` can be directly access if it's declared as `Public`

Comment: @SharatChandra I assume that you want to use the structure of `ClassB` right?

Comment: Type ClassB_obj.sampleStruct not defined

Comment: don't use `ClassB_obj.sampleStruc` but instead `Dim classb_struct As ClassB.Struct`

Answer (score 0):

Well your struct is private have you tried making it public?